# use a regex capture in a pgSQL select

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I've never used a regex in SQL. If I capture something like this in javascript, how can I refer back to the capture in pgSQL like I can with the 2nd element in javascript `match()` method?

```
var str = 'thomas-var1="SOME VAL1" thomas=var2="SOME VAL2" thomas-var-3="the value i want" thomas-var-4="SOME_VAL4"';

var re = /thomas-var-3="(.+?)"/i;

var new_str = str.match(re);

console.log(new_str[1]);
```

How can I put that into a `SELECT` statement so that I can say something like, retrieving the value `"the value i want"` from `thomas-var-3`?

```
SELECT * FROM forms WHERE name LIKE '%bill%' AND category = MY REGEX CAPTURE
```

rendering so something like"

```
SELECT * FROM forms WHERE name LIKE '%bill%' AND category ='the value i want'
```

Comment: Can you post some example input and output? (And -- have you read through [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)?)

Comment: Are you interacting with postgres directly from the javascript? What technology are you using to go from javascript to the SQL statement?

Comment: @JDiPierro Javascript plays no part in it. That's the only way I knew how to write the pattern though, so I used it in the question to demonstrate what I was trying to do with SQL.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm confused about what you're trying to match against then.. The match that you want to fill in.. Do you want postgres to be pulling it out of some other column while it's searching through?

Comment: @JDiPierro Right. So it could be like `SELECT * FROM firstTable WHERE parentCat = (SELECT cat FROM secondTable WHERE cat = ...pattern...`

Answer (score 1):

Using a subselect and the substring method you should be able to achieve what you want like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM firstTable 
WHERE parentCat = (SELECT cat 
                   FROM secondTable 
                   WHERE cat in substring(column_to_capture_from from 'thomas-var-3="(.+?)' ));
```

from http://www.regular-expressions.info/postgresql.html

> *If there is a match, and the regex has one or more capturing groups, the text matched by the first capturing group is returned.*

Comment: using `IN` instead of `=` is safer in case the sub-select returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

you can use not regex, but [hstore extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for this, like:

```
str := 'thomas-var1="SOME VAL1" thomas-var2="SOME VAL2" thomas-var-3="the value i want"'
str := replace(replace(str, '=', '=>'), '" ', '", ')

select *
from forms
where name like '%bill%' and category = hstore(str)->'thomas-var-3'
```